# Error when trying to run redis-trib.rb

Tags: ruby, error-handling, redis

I have installed and setup redis 3.0.2 cluster on Ubuntu 14.04,but when i try to run the command:

```
./redis-trib.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- redis (LoadError)
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from ./redis-trib.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

I have ruby installed using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration
```

But still get the same error. I also tried installing ruby with:

```
rvm get head
rvm relaod
rvm install ruby-2.2.2
```

And still get the same error. How can i resolve this? I have been googling for hours and cannot get a solution.

Comment: can i assume that you installed redis over rubygems with sudo? This will break your depencies and the programm would work if you run it as sudo. You could try fixing the permissions trough ```sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.rvm```

Comment: I followed the instruction from https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04 to install ryby and gem redis and the scriot runs fine now